# Proper way to slideToggle then dynamically create content and slideToggle back

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, slidetoggle

I have a div with some elements. When the users selects a button the div is cleared and is populated dynamically with new content. I run slideToggle before clearing the div and after populating it. The first toggle that hides the div works fine. The second slideToggle doesn't run (the new div just loads without an animation).

Ive spent a couple hours on this trying different things (callback functions, .on, promises, placing the 2nd slideToggle function in different parts of the code,  etc..). I finally got it to work by using setTimeout with a time of 1 millisecond. Even though its working I am more confused than ever and questioning everything in my life. Help me understand whats going on please.

**Working code:**

```
changeCat:function(catName){
    domObject.$positionsDiv.slideToggle(function(){
        domObject.$positionsDiv.html('');
        let yourCategories = getSubFolders(catName+"/");

        if(catName==='s'){
            tSCat.drawCats(yourCategories);

        } else if(catName==='g'){
            tGCat.drawCats(yourCategories);
        }
        setTimeout(function (){
            domObject.$positionsDiv.slideToggle(function(){
                resizeCanvas()
            });
        }, 1)

    });
},
```

Whats really confusing me is if I console log the height of the target div.

- The console log I expect to be called last ("height 5") is called first.
- The div height ("height 3") is the height of the fully populated div before I call the second toggle (so why doesn't it work?).

**Non-working Code (no timeout, with console logs)**

```
changeCat:function(catName){
    domObject.$positionsDiv.slideToggle(function(){
        console.log('height 1: ' + domObject.$positionsDiv.height())
        domObject.$positionsDiv.html('');
        console.log('height 2: ' + domObject.$positionsDiv.height())
        let yourCategories = getSubFolders(catName+"/");

        if(catName==='s'){
            tSCat.drawCats(yourCategories);

        } else if(catName==='g'){
            tGCat.drawCats(yourCategories);
        }

        console.log('height 3: ' + domObject.$positionsDiv.height())
            domObject.$positionsDiv.slideToggle(function(){
                console.log('height 4: ' + domObject.$positionsDiv.height())
                resizeCanvas()
            });
    });
    console.log('height 5: ' + domObject.$positionsDiv.height())
},
```

Console log returned in this order with the following values:

```
height 5: 359.333 
height 1: 2214 
height 2: 0
height 3: 3744
height 4: 324
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "traditional" way is to put the "show" code inside the "hide" callback:

```js
$("#d").slideToggle(function() {
  $(this).html("a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>");
  $(this).slideToggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='d'>
  1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>
</div>
```

What's happening when you call "show" after a 1ms timeout is the same as if you call "show" immediately.

`.slideToggle()` uses `.animate()` and every `.animate()` call on the same DOM node gets queued.  So what happens:

- your "hide" starts
- the "show" is queued
- the hide completes and the callback is called setting the content while "invisible"
- the show auto de-queues

```js
$("#d").slideToggle(function() {
  $(this).html("a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>");
});
$(this).slideToggle()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='d'>
  1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: "What's happening when you call "show" after a 1ms timeout is the same as if you call "show" immediately." ... Thanks for the reply. Maybe I'm missing it but isn't the "non-working code" I posted doing exactly that?

Comment: Apologies, they're not the same in your case as they're both called from within the callback, whereas my example has it called outside the callback.  In your case, if it works with a minimal setTimeout then the cause will be something else that runs async/possibly an event handler in between so you need to wait for it to "finish" - which the setTimeout does.  So most likely something in `tGCat.drawCats`

Comment: Ah ya figured it was probably something to do with that. Thank you. Do you think that is that the reason for the console.log outputting "height 5" first?

Comment: Yes, height 5 is the first console.log to run because javascript is single-threaded so the animation doesn't/can't start until your code completes.